# Parsing JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I have the following code:

```
var addressInfo = [];
for(var x in address_components_root){
    addressInfo.push(address_components_root[x].long_name+"|||"+address_components_root[x].types[0]);
}


for(var d in addressInfo) {
    addressI = addressInfo[d].split("|||");
    if (addressI[1]=="street_number") {
        window.alert("street");
    }
}
```

`address_components_root` is a JSON encoded response as found at http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

How would I parse this json correctly like for example using `eval` so I don;t need to manually assign all the data?

Comment: JSON = Javascript Object Notation

Comment: @Sandro: And what do you want to say with that?

Comment: I just wanted to point that out. It is close to javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern browsers you can use `JSON.parse([json string]);`. In older browsers you need a JSON library: see [this page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) - use the `json2.js` file.

Comment: Ok, I receive the error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object function json_decode(str_json)` - is this because the data I get from google is already an object? Sorry, bit of a JSON noob here

Comment: It works here with the link you provided. See http://jsfiddle.net/hE8xf/ for the right syntax. What's in `json_decode`?

Comment: My bad, was using googles api. Already returns a JSON object. What a fool. I was using the same function on a server side version of the script that fetched the data from the REST api and then the client side which fetched it from the JS api.